# App crashing after pushing button, but the action is working

Tags: android, button, android-studio, compiler-errors

Maybe someone sees an error, the problem is that when i push `btn2 (button 2)` and `btn3 (button 3)` app `crashes`, but action still works, i.e `video` is running and `PDF` opens, while `button 1` is working correctly...

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    configureImageButton();

    mCamera = getCameraInstance();

    mPreview = new CameraPreview(this, mCamera);
    FrameLayout layout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.camera_View);
    layout.addView(mPreview);


    controlInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getBaseContext());
    View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_main, layout, false);
    layout.addView(view);

}

public Camera getCameraInstance(){
    Camera c = null;
    try {
        c = Camera.open();
        c.setDisplayOrientation(90);
    }
    catch (Exception e){
    }
    return c;
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    mpAudio.release();
}

private void configureImageButton() {

    ImageButton btn1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton);// audio button
    ImageButton btn2 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton2); // video button
    ImageButton btn3= (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton3);//reading button

    btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(View v) {
                                    mpAudio = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this,R.raw.tirepressuremonitoringsystem);
                                    mpAudio.start();
                                }
                            }
    );

    btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(View v) {
                                    startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Activity2.class));
                                }
                            }
    );

    btn3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(View v) {
                                    readPDF();
                                }
                            }
    );
}

private void readPDF()
{
    AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();

    InputStream in = null;
    OutputStream out = null;
    File file = new File(getFilesDir(), "tirepressuremonitoringsystem3.pdf");
    try
    {
        in = assetManager.open("tirepressuremonitoringsystem3.pdf");
        out = openFileOutput(file.getName(), Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);

        copyFile(in, out);
        in.close();
        in = null;
        out.flush();
        out.close();
        out = null;
    } catch (Exception e)
    {
        Log.e("tag", e.getMessage());
    }

    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setDataAndType(
            Uri.parse("file://" + getFilesDir() + "/tirepressuremonitoringsystem3.pdf"),
            "application/pdf");

    startActivity(intent);
}

private void copyFile(InputStream in, OutputStream out) throws IOException
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int read;
    while ((read = in.read(buffer)) != -1)
    {
        out.write(buffer, 0, read);
    }
}

public void playSound () throws IOException {
    AssetFileDescriptor afd = getAssets().openFd("tirepressuremonitoringsystem.mp3");
    mpAudio = new MediaPlayer();
    mpAudio.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(),afd.getStartOffset(),afd.getLength());
    mpAudio.prepare();
    mpAudio.start();

}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}



}
```

Comment: have you defined second activity in manifest ?

Comment: I guess you have some error in Activity2. Post Logcat  we can find out what is the error

Comment: Can you post your xml where you have defined buttons

Comment: http://paste.ofcode.org/4s9BtyP44X6QPKSDmfWdgP

Comment: ONE MORE THING THAT I NOTICED - WHEN I FIRST OF ALL PRESS BUTTON 1, AFTER IT PROGRAMS DONT CRASHES ANYMORE WHATEVER I DO . make nosense... but if i firstly press button2 or button3 it crashes

Comment: still crashes  @Clairvoyant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It crashed if you dont press btn1 because without press it, `mpAudio` will be null.
Then when `onPause` call, `mpAudio.release();` will cause NullPointerException.

Note that:  onPause is called whenever the activity is not shown on screen but is still running(in your case, you start other activity with btn2,3 then it will be called).

Please correct to

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if(mpAudio!=null)
        mpAudio.release();
}
```

Have fun!

Comment: simple by check the stick on left side of my post. Remember this will help other to know the correct answer, and I got some reputation score